# javaScriptWindowObjectCleared signal is not invoked while html page loaded in qwebview

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I am new to QT.  I have been trying to see the bridge between javascript and Qt Class.

What I did:

1)  I have a button and connected clicked signal to on_pushButton_clicked, also I have qwebview instance.

In on_pushButton_clicked:

...

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:\\whoami\\sd\\index.html");


  QObject::connect(ui->webView->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
                     this, SLOT(addJSObject()));

  ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl(url));
....
```

and in addJSObject,

```
void MainWindow::addJSObject()
{
    qDebug () <<"Inside addJSObject";
    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(QString("mBridge"), m_bridge);
    qDebug () <<"Nooo. I m not invoked..";
}
```

Problem:

It compiles without error, and html file is displayed in the qwebview, but addJSObject callback is not invoked.

Could someone help me in order to resolve this issue?.. I must have done some silly mistake. :(.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that your MainWindow: 1) inherits QObject 2) has Q_OBJECT macro 3) has a slot addJSObject().

For example mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MainWindow();

private slots:
  void addJSObject();

};
```

If this is correct, you should be able to connect to addJSObject() without static QObject::connect(). Just use connect() when referring to this as signal target object.

One way to just check, that your signalling works is to try using QTimer timeout signal:

```
QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, SLOT(addJSObject()));
```